# Convert C# if Statement Into SQL Server if Statement

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to convert an C# if statement into a SQL Server if statement so I can use it within a sql server statement to filter record based on this condition.

```
public bool checkSourceSystem(bool A, bool B, bool C, string SendToA, string SendToB, string SendToC)
    {
        int count = 0;

        if (A == true || B == true || C == true)
        {
            if(A == true && SendToA == "Success")
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            if(B == true && SendToB== "Success")
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (C == true && SendToC == "Success")
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

What I did as per below. But I dont think this one correct.

```
SELECT CASE

WHEN A = '1' AND SendToA = '1' THEN 'true' 

WHEN B = '1' AND SendToB = '1' THEN 'true' 

WHEN C = '1' AND SendToC = '1' THEN 'true'

ELSE 'false'

END 

FROM Table1
```

A,B,C,SendToA,SendToB,SendToC are fields in a table and the values for `true` and `Success` = 1 in sqlserver.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: How far have you got? What do your tables look like?

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did you get?

Comment: @BugFinder I tried using If..ELSE in SQL server and all  I got is syntax error. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql)

Comment: Then show that code - thats the bit we can likely help you with - we wont write it for you

Comment: Hi I've already edited and added with sample of SQL statement which I don't think its correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `C#` method, the return value is `false` when:

1. `A`, `B`, `C` are all `false`
2. `A` is false or `A` is `true`, but `SendToA` is not `Success`
3. `B` is false or `B` is `true`, but `SendToB` is not `Success`
4. `C` is false or `C` is `true`, but `SendToC` is not `Success`

This means that `true` is only ever returned when:

1. `A` == `B` == `C` == `true` and
2. `SendToA` == `SendToB` == `SendToC` == `Success`

This can then be shortened to:

```
public bool checkSourceSystem(bool A, bool B, bool C, string SendToA, string SendToB, string SendToC)
{
    return (A && B && C) && SendToA == "Success" && SendToB == "Success" && SendToC == "Success";
}
```

This corresponds to the following `CASE` statement:

```
select *,
    (
        CASE WHEN A=1
            AND B=1
            AND C=1
            AND SendToA = 1
            AND SendToB = 1
            AND SendToC = 1
        THEN 'true'
        ELSE 'false'
        END 
    ) as TrueFalse
from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **Function in SQL** with below statement which will return you RESULT (True/False).

```
DECLARE @A BIT=0
DECLARE @B BIT=0
DECLARE @C BIT=0
DECLARE @SendToA VARCHAR(50)=''
DECLARE @SendToB VARCHAR(50)=''
DECLARE @SendToC VARCHAR(50)=''
DECLARE @Count INT=0

DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(50)=''

IF (@A=1 OR @B=1 OR @C=1)
BEGIN
    IF (@A=1 AND @SendToA='Success')
    BEGIN
        SET @Count=@Count+1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Result='False'
    END

    IF (@B=1 AND @SendToB='Success')
    BEGIN
        SET @Count=@Count+1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Result='False'
    END

    IF (@C=1 AND @SendToC='Success')
    BEGIN
        SET @Count=@Count+1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Result='False'
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Result='False'
END

IF @Count>0
BEGIN
    SET @Result='True'
END

SELECT @Result AS Result
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add this function into where clause in my select statement. Using this function(if...ELSE) instead of CASE in where clause for filter.